# WebLogic Server Version: 12.1.2.0.0 Attempting to precompile

Tags: weblogic12c

I am deploying my JAVA EE ear app. as usual in WL server, 
but suddenly it seems that everytime WL is trying precompile all the JSP again and the deployment take ages

```
12.1.2.0.0.>
ST> <Info> <HTTP> <BEA-101343> <my_devices: Attempting to precompile /WEB-INF/jsp/template/header.jsp, since the class file associated with it was found to be out-of-date.>
ST> <Info> <HTTP> <BEA-101295> <Recompiling JSP [ServletContext@29540787[app:my_devices module:my_devices path:null spec-version:3.0]], resource [/WEB-INF/jsp/template/popupHeader.jsp], because it is stale. It was previously compiled using a different version of WebLogic Server.
12.1.2.0.0.>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precompile is a good thing !!

But if you want to disable it to get a faster deployment, change your weblogic.xml file and include the following:

```
<jsp-descriptor>
          <jsp-param>
               <param-name>precompile</param-name>
               <param-value>false</param-value>
          </jsp-param>
</jsp-descriptor>
```

That should help you on this !